# Как указать анимации значение из TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, анимация

Я создал свой `<ControlTemplate>` для `Button`. Я хочу сделать анимацию **hover-effect** для этой кнопки. **При наведении** цвет текст становиться красным, а при `MouseLeave` событии цвет должен вернуться в **исходное** состояние.

Можно задать возвращение к цвету текста **при обычном состоянии** явным образом: `<ColorAnimation To="Black" />`.

Но что, если я создал другую кнопку с этим же шаблоном, но хочу чтобы цвет текста у неё был по умолчанию жёлтым.

Как мне быть? Цвет при `MouseLeave` поменяется на **Black**.

Можно ли задать для `<ColorAnimation To="" />` значение, привязанное к указанному при создании кнопки. Вроде этого:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource temp}" Foreground="Yellow"/>
```

**P.S.** *Создание другого шаблона не вариант*

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `To ="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"`, не?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, к сожалению нет. `InvalidOperationException: Не удается зафиксировать данное дерево шкалы времени Storyboard для использования в различных потоках`.

Comment: **Foreground** задаю, если что для `<ContentControl>`

Comment: Ну тогда просто убирайте `To`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо! Сработало!

Comment: Кстати все это можно сделать [одним](https://pastebin.com/6dgR9e5H) триггером, без `MouseLeave`.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду PropertyTrigger, то он не подойдёт, т.к. мне нужнен плавный переход.

Comment: Я вам ссылку дал с примером "плавного перехода" (анимации), всего одним триггером.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, извинияюсь! Не заметил. Спасибо!